# Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I am getting the error in the title when retrieving records from postgres using laravel's query builder.

The source code is below.

```
AvailableReservationDatetime::query()
            ->select(DB::raw('
            available_date
            ,array_agg(available_time) available_times
        '))
            ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('reservations')
                ->where('reservation_date', 'available_date')
                ->whereBetween('available_time', ['reservation_time', 'end_time']);
        })
            ->groupBy('available_date')
            ->get();
```

The error is in both arguments of the where function in the callback function within the whereNotExist function.

For your information, the middle SQL is as follows.

```
select available_date ,array_agg(available_time) available_times from "available_reservation_datetimes" where not exists (select 1 from "reservations" where "reservation_date" = available_date and "available_time" between reservation_time and end_time) group by "available_date"
```

Curiously, when the above SQL is executed directly in postgres without laravel, the records are successfully retrieved.

Why does this happen? I assume it has something to do with the functionality of laravel.

I would like to add that the query can be executed successfully if the type is converted as follows.

```
AvailableReservationDatetime::query()
            ->select(DB::raw('
            available_date
            ,array_agg(available_time) available_times
        '))
            ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                ->from('reservations')
                ->whereRaw('CAST(available_date AS DATE) = CAST(reservation_date AS DATE)')
                ->whereRaw('CAST(available_time AS TIME) BETWEEN CAST(reservation_time AS TIME) AND CAST(end_time AS TIME)');
            })
            ->groupBy('available_date')
            ->get();
```

Comment: What are the data types for *_date and *_time fields in the  Postgres table(s)?

Comment: The date type is a date, and
time type is time without time zone.